# Encrypted swap is not activated on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partition, swap

If I check the usage of the swap partition in my OS (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
$ cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
$
```

I obtain an empty result. But this partition should actually exist, named `/dev/sda6` and as large as 8 GB.

```
$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print free
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54323 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size        Type      File system    Flags
        32,3kB  1049kB  1016kB                Free Space
 1      1049kB  160GB   160GB       primary   ext4           boot
        160GB   160GB   1048kB                Free Space
 2      160GB   320GB   160GB       extended
 5      160GB   312GB   152GB       logical   ext4
 6      312GB   320GB   7997MB      logical
        320GB   320GB   352kB                 Free Space
```

In partition number 6 the `File system` is empty and it should be instead `linux-swap`. These partitions were created with the Ubuntu installation wizard. Is there something wrong? And how to use that 8 GB space as a swap partition?

---

As requested in the comments, this is the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=bd20abfc-6ff1-4c3c-a77d-0e85f5c19af9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=29599282-3815-4aa7-80ba-9058898e7a73 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=c34d62e9-68e8-495a-869b-b107b5741c7e none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

During the installation I choose to encrypt my home directory (then I choose to made it later and I never did it). I don't remember the encryption of the swap too! I don't need an encrypted swap partition.

Moreover:

```
$ cat /etc/crypttab 
cryptswap1 UUID=c34d62e9-68e8-495a-869b-b107b5741c7e /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3005       2082        922         42         46        534
-/+ buffers/cache:       1500       1504
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Comment: @StephenKitt Sure, I made it as requested.

Comment: Thanks; could you also add the contents of `/etc/crypttab` (if there's nothing sensitive there)?

Comment: What's the output of `free -m` ?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, it has nothing "private"; I never even choose a key for encryption here.

Comment: @SHW I edited my post with that output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Jan Henke, this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/953875) for Ubuntu 14.04 (and 12.04).
If during installation the user chooses to encrypt his home partition, the swap partition will be encrypted too, but it will be *not available* to the OS.

A direct `mkswap` may not work (as suggested by Stephen Kitt), because of the encryption of the interested partition.

The solution that worked for my system was the following:

1. Run `sudo fdisk -l` and find the partition maked as swap partition. In this example, `/dev/sda6` will be used. **If you found another partition, use its name instead of `sda6` in all the steps**!
2. Compare its name with the partition used as swap during the installation (so, before encryption), shown in `/etc/fstab` in the line (1)

   `# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation`

   and make sure they are the same.
3. Run `sudo -s` and then `umount /dev/sda6`.
4. Run `mkswap /dev/sda6`. In the output, a UUID should be produced.
5. Use *that* UUID to run

   `echo "RESUME=UUID=143c43d8-0a77-4d62-a7ae-f53a8e0229a9" > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

   (the UUID used here is just an example).
6. Run

   `echo "cryptswap1 /dev/sda6 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256" > /etc/crypttab`
7. Run

   `update-initramfs -u
   exit`
8. Reboot.

After rebooting, verify that your system is actually using a swap partition. Check it with `cat /proc/swaps` or `swapon -s`. The output of the latter command should be like the following:

```
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                  partition       8787964 0       -1
```

This solution is from [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224129). I rewrote it entirely here according to the Stackexchange guidelines.

---

(1) In my question I posted all the contents of my `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: I think that you're missing a step here for creating the `cryptswap1` dev mapper.  I believe you need to run the command `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap` after I ran that I was able to get the `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` that pointed to `/dev/dm-0` after the running of the `update-initramfs -u` and the reboot.

Comment: Why do you create file /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume? Resume from hibernate will not work with encrypted swap anyway. If it is not used, then also step 7 is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

That is a well known problem with encrypted swaps on Ubuntu. In the default setup it often fails to mount the swap on boot.

If I remember correctly, you can add the `noauto` option to the swap entry in `/etc/fstab`, then edit your `/etc/rc.local` and add these lines to it (before the `return 0` at the end, it is important to keep that)

```
sleep 1
swapon /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
```

That worked for me, but I am not sure any more if it required recreating the swap partition or not. Am also no longer using Ubuntu, so the above solution is from my memory from the time I was affected by that problem too.

Answer (score -1):

You need to execute the commands:

```
# mkswap <Your_Swap_Partition>
# swapon <Your_Swap_Partition>
```

You just have created the partition but not yet formatted with file system 
type.

Comment: No, `/etc/fstab` points to an encrypted swap...